# Linux Command Line - List all non-accessible files and folders

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I am trying to list all the files and folders which I do not have permission to read and modify.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

files do have three kinds of rights. one for owner of the file, one for the group members the file belongs to and one for everybody. files that are not read/writeable by everybody not read/writeable by one of your groups and not read/writeable by your user can be found with the find utitlity like this:

```
$ find / '( -not -perm -o+w,o+r ) -and ( -not -group <groupname> -perm -g+w,g+r ) -and ( -not -user <username> -perm -u+w,u+r )'
```

if you have to check for more group you could expand the term inside the second parentheses:

```
$ find / '( -not -perm -o+w,o+r ) -and ( -not -group <groupname> -perm -g+w,g+r -not -group <group2> ) -and ( -not -user <username> -perm -u+w,u+r )'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find to list all files

```
find searchpath
```

Ignore the output, since only the error is what you are interested in.

```
find searchpath >/dev/null
```

Use awk to get a nice list of all files

```
find searchpath 2>&1 >/dev/null | awk '{ print substr($2,2,length($2)-3) }'
```

Notice this assumes all files doesn't have spaces in their names, to deal with that just change the awk sctipt.

Comment: The OP wants all **files** and directories he can't read. This approach will only give him the directories.